# Processor Budgeting

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor, cpu, processing

How do I figure out if a microcontroller has enough processing speed to handle particularly "intensive" tasks?

Specifically, I am a university student looking to design a robot that uses OpenCV and a LADAR. Our team has an ODROID X2. I figure the ARM is fast enough but how can I make sure?

Comment: You find an ARM system that is much faster, port the code, and find out.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Is trying it out really the only way? Time is limited and if I could have the foresight to not go down a long road towards a dead end, that would be ideal.

Comment: That board is 'based on Exynos4412 Prime 1.7GHz ARM Cortex-A9 Quad Core with 2GB memory'. You can not get much better than this, perhaps with some small intel i5/i7-based board.

Comment: Wow, yeah, that's a big board. I can't see there being a problem with that unless the code is terrible.

Comment: Cannot give you direct answer, just some info. I have OpenCV on i5 PC and Raspberry Pi (Linux, about 850MHz?) connected with USB web cam. CPU load vary hugely depending on which function you call in OpenCV. Have not done myself, I read web blog by people who tested and reported Raspberry Pi working at 3 to 5 frame per seconds, at 640X480 resolution, with typical application of finding a color block. PC is much faster.  Do you mean Lidar (or Ladar)?

Comment: @Ninja48 Are you research or undergrad? If research, you work on a lot of unknown and target, cpu load, algorithm are highly unknown at project start, presumably it is now Aug and you are shopping. If I were you, I get very powerful CPU, i5 quad core or higher (or the ARM equivalent, which I am not familiar with). You may consider reading existing paper on past works that were 'best similar' to your intended works, see what CPU they use. If paper is 1 or 2 years old, at least double or triple CPU power than past papers, if you are at research level and have fair to good funding. Best wishes.

Answer (score 2):

Oftentimes performance is not limited by the pure processing speed of the CPU, but instead other bottlenecks in the system - RAM, Flash, Serial I/O, etc. This becomes more of an issue with more complicated peripherals. While you may be able to *theoretically* compute processor load, this is very, very difficult. The right way to do this is to use benchmarking. Test how much your LIDAR interface and other interfaces require, and also (this is very important) continue to test throughout the development process so if processor usage spikes after a certain feature is added then you can go back and figure out whether there's a better way.

At the end of the day though, Hardware is cheap - when in doubt go big.

Comment: Fully agree with the last line, especially true if it is University research work and one never knows what the works may turn out to be. (OP does not stated Grad or undergrad)

Answer (score 1):

You can run a simulator and run code benchmarks on the simulator. Or run code on an eval board with a comparable processor and do benchmarks there.

I don't know what OpenCV and LADAR are, but I assume you're compiling the code yourself, so you should use the same compiler you'll be using for the target processor.

Even if it appears to run, you really want to know how much margin you have so some tiny change won't break the code. If you have access only to an eval board it's possible to do crude things like toggle an output pin when the processor is idle, in which case the average output voltage can be used to roughly determine how much of the processor bandwidth is still available.